# Cannot compile my program for Homework?

Tags: c++

Hi I am having a problem in compiling a program for my homework. So essentially we are given a program by the professor and need to implement a user header file that allows for the functions in the given program to run.The program describes the motion of a walker on an xy plane. The user header file would need to include the functions used by the program. We are given 2 programs so here is one of the programs we are given. We need to write the Walker.h file.

Given Program

```
    #include "Walker.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      Walker w;
      int dx=0, dy=0;
      try
      {
        cin >> w;
        cout << w << endl;
        cin >> dx >> dy;
        while ( cin )
        {
          w.move_by(dx,dy);
          cout << w << endl;
          cin >> dx >> dy;
        }
        cout << w << endl;
      }
      catch ( invalid_argument& e )
      {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
      }
    }
```

and here is my header file and corresponding cpp file.

```
#ifndef Walker_H
#define Walker_H

class Walker{

 public:
 int xcoord, ycoord;
 Walker()
 {
    xcoord = 0;
    ycoord = 0;
 };

 Walker (int x , int y)
 {
   xcoord = x;
   ycoord = y;
 };


   void move_by(int dx, int dy);

   int get_x(void);

   int get_y(void);
};
   std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Walker& w);

   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Walker& w);


#endif
```

and this it the cpp file for the header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Walker.h"
#include <stdexcept>


   std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Walker& w)
   {
     return is >> w.xcoord >> w.ycoord;
   };
   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Walker& w)
   {
     return os << "(" << w.xcoord << "," << w.ycoord << ")";
   };

   void Walker::move_by(int dx, int dy)
   {
     while(cin)
     {
       xcoord += dx;
       ycoord += dy;
     }
   };

   int Walker:: get_x (void)
   {
     return xcoord;
   };

   int Walker:: get_y (void)
   {
     return ycoord;
   };
```

Please help, I thought my code looked right but there are a lot of notes when I try to compile it. I do not know where to start.

Here are the first few error messages.

walk.cpp:14:9: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’ and ‘Walker’)
     cin >> w;
         ^

/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/istream:120:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Walker’ to ‘std::basic_istream::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream ::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream& (*)(std::basic_istream&)}’

/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/istream:124:7: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Walker’ to ‘std::basic_istream::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios& (*)(std::basic_ios&)}’

Comment: Start by not tagging `c++`-questions as `c`?

Comment: What are some of the *first* errors you see?

Comment: All i can see is homework..

Comment: Here are some of the errors I see  note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Walker’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’            ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ . The first several errors are base on "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Walker’ to _____.

Comment: Instead of homework code dumping, have you clean compiled it, debugged it?

Comment: `while(cin)` looks extremely misplaced in `move_by`. Also, functions are not terminated by semicolon, only classes.

Comment: The easiest way (although it may take longer, until you begin to recognize certain errors so can fix them quickly) is to take the very first error message. (that error message will contain the file name, the line number, the column number, a statement of the error, and which compile/link parameter forced the raising of the error message.  You can look online for details about the compile/link parameter.  Your code contains the reason for the error message.  Go to that file, that line, fix the error, save, re-compile, etc

Comment: For what it's worth, semicolons after function blocks in .cpp files are unnecessary and may lead to warnings/errors in some IDEs/compilers.

Comment: Why are there so many questions on S.O. that say "I get an error" but then don't bother including the error. This question is better than a lot - at least we know it's a compile error!

Comment: The first error is  error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘Walker’)
     cin >> w;  I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Edit the question to include the error messages.

Comment: a couple of leading questions:  1) why is the data `public` rather than `private`?   Why are the override functions for `<<` and `>>` outside the class definition?

Comment: I put the override functions outside the class definition because "'istream' does not name a type" error when I put it in the class definition with a 'friend' type. I googled the error and the results said to move outside the class definition. Would there be a different way of fixing that error?

Comment: Walker.h uses iostream stuff but doesn't include `<iostream>` header

Comment: the code seems to be missing the destructor method, the copy constructor, and the assignment constructor.  The two posted constructors  could be made into a single constructor by using default values.    Usually in the constructor, the fields to be set are written more like: classname( int x=0, int y=0): xcoord, ycoord;  Then nothing needs to be in the body of the 'default' constructor and it will work with no parameters, 1 parameter or 2 parameters

Comment: first error message: effectively says the line: `#include <iostream>` is missing from the class header file

Comment: you could cleanup the code quite a bit by inserting the statement: `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0):

the following examples were taken from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm  which is a sub page from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

here is an example of how to overload the `<<` operator and `>>` operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Distance
{
   private:
      int feet;             // 0 to infinite
      int inches;           // 0 to 12
   public:
      // required constructors
      Distance(){
         feet = 0;
         inches = 0;
      }
      Distance(int f, int i){
         feet = f;
         inches = i;
      }
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, 
                                       const Distance &D )
      { 
         output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
         return output;            
      }

      friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input, Distance &D )
      { 
         input >> D.feet >> D.inches;
         return input;            
      }
};
```

You might also want to read this: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html  which gives a lot of 'pointers' about how to code a lot of different situations.